# Is a map mapping infinity to infinity conformal at infinity?

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

The map is the following:
$$f(z)=
\begin{cases}
z*e^z & \text{$z \neq \infty$}\\
\infty & \text{$z= \infty$} 
\end{cases}$$

This function maps $\infty$ to $\infty$, so how to check if it's conformal at infinity? Any help are appreciated.

Comment: Does it really map (complex) infinity to infinity? Along the negative real line, you have $\lim_{x \to -\infty} x e^{x} = 0$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are maps that are conformal at $\infty$. Yours is not. In order to check for conformality introduce a new complex coordinate $\zeta$ via $z={1\over \zeta}$ in the neighborhood of $z=\infty$ as well as in the neighborhood of the assumed value $w=\infty$. In your example this would mean looking at the function
$$g(\zeta):={1\over f(1/\zeta)}=\zeta\cdot e^{-1/\zeta}\qquad(\zeta\ne0)$$
and $g(0):=0$ in the neighborhood of $\zeta=0$.

On the other hand, the function $h(z):=z$ of course is conformal at $z=\infty$, as are Moebius transformations 
$$T(z):={az+b\over cz +d},\qquad ad-bc\ne0\ .$$